# From ckeditor 5 plugins bulleted List and numbered List does not work in React , can anyone tell me why

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react, ckeditor5-plugin

My CKEditor code blok

```
<CKEditor
                                editor={ClassicEditor}
                                config={{
                                    ckfinder: {
                                        // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
                                        uploadUrl:
                                            'https://localhost:44374/api/v1/announcements/upload-file?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
                                    },
                                    mediaEmbed: {
                                        previewsInData: true
                                    },

                                    table: {
                                        contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells']
                                    }
                                }}
                                onReady={editor => {
                                    editor.editing.view.change(writer => {
                                        writer.setStyle('height', '300px', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot());
                                        writer.setStyle(
                                            'z-index',
                                            '999999 !important',
                                            editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
                                        );
                                    });
                                }}
                                data={form.body}
                                onChange={(event, editor) => {
                                    const data = editor.getData();
                                    setForm({
                                        ...form,
                                        body: data
                                    });
                                }}
                            />
```

When I click the icons, only the Title changes, the Bulluted and Numbered list is not added.
Does Anybody know the reason ???

Comment: same problem, have you find the solution?